# I am very new in laravel I want to join two table according to department . How i want given below

Tags: sql, database, laravel, join

Here is the Cse_department student database screenshot

[image]

i want to join to Administration table data where dept=1 i give the screenshot

[image]

I want administration table  which dept=1 he get the all data from the cse_department. how can i join which type of relationship.
please provide the laravel query.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question about that code and we'll try to assist.

Comment: i recommend to learn https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

#### As you are new to Laravel, I would recommend learning about [Laravel eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)

You could use a single table for all the departments and differentiate each department by `dept` as you have already.

```
$CseDeptStudent = DeptStundent::where('dept', '1')
           ->with('administration')
           ->get();
```

I'm guessing it is having `1:N` relationship.

In the model `DeptStundent`, you need to define the relationship as below.

```
class DeptStundent extends Model
{
    public function administration()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductMeta::class', 'dept','dept');        
    }
}
```

In the model `Administration`, you need to define the relationship as below.

```
class Administration extends Model
{
    public function deptStundent()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('DeptStundent::class', 'dept','dept');        
    }
}
```